# Oracle split partition to a different tablespace

Tags: oracle, split, partition, tablespace

Is it possible to split a partition and move the new sub partition to a different table space?

Lets say I have table space t1 and t2. For a table x I have only one partition p1 that sits in t1. Can I split p1 into p1 and p2 and move only p2 to tablespace t2? Will the following query work?

```
ALTER TABLE X
SPLIT PARTITION P1 -- currently in tablespace T1
AT (10, TO_DATE('20150916000000', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
INTO (PARTITION P2
      tablespace T2,
      PARTITION P1) PARALLEL 10;
```

Comment: Did you try it out? It should work, do you get any error?

Comment: i havent tried it out, since this will impact millions of rows, and my worry is even if it gets split to the specified table space...will future queries on this table return data that belongs to the partition in the other tablespace?

Comment: Queries (or any DML) are completely independent on tablespaces. But you may ask. what happens if you get a new partition.

Comment: Yes! the split to separate tablespace does work...and post the split, select statements on table pertaining to data in the new sub partition returns the expected rows. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Oracle 11g, it's possible to move an existing partition to a new tablespace.

So, you can probably do it in 2 steps-

1. split the partition
2. move the relevant partition to a new tablespace

Example -

Table name - Test_history_umts

partition name - sys_541

New table space name- data1

Query-

```
alter table test_history_umts move sys_541 to tablespace data1;
```

Hope it helps!!